# How to use Koin in multiple module?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

There are two modules in my android project, app module and lib module.

Both these two modules need Koin for D.I., so I call `startKoin` in `MyApplication` class in app module, and `IninKointContentProvider` in lib module as below.

```
// app module
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin(this, modules1)
    }
}

// lib module
class InitKoinContentProvider : ContentProvider() {
    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        startKoin(context.applicationContext, modules2)
        return true
    }
}
```

Then app crashed and shown this message

```
Caused by: org.koin.error.BeanOverrideException: Try to override definition with Single [class='android.content.Context'], but override is not allowed. Use 'override' option in your definition or module.
```

I guess `startKoin` can be called only one time.

The solution I found is merging two koin modules then calling `startKoin` in `MyApplication`, but I don't like it. Lib module may be imported by other android project which doesn't use koin, in that case, I think calling `startKoin` in `InitKoinContentProvider` is better.

Any solution for this problem?? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I found the best solution inspired by @laalto's answer, thanks!

Upgrade to koin 2.0, then use KoinApplication and customized KoinComponent to create a isolated koin context, it can let lib module using koin without any initializing call by app module, still start koin in ContentProvider. The whole code may like below.

```
// app module
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MyApplication)
            modules(module{
                viewModel { MainViewModel() }
            })
        }
    }
}

class MainActivity: AppCompactActivity() {
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModel()
}



// lib module
internal object MyKoinContext {
    lateinit var koinApplication: KoinApplication
}

interface MyKoinComponent : KoinComponent {
    override fun getKoin(): Koin {
        return MyKoinContext.koinApplication.koin
    }
}

class InitKoinContentProvider : ContentProvider() {
    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        MyKoinContext.koinApplication = koinApplication {
            androidContext(context.applicationContext)
            modules(module{
                viewModel { FooViewModel() }
            })
        }
        return true
    }
}

class FooActivity: AppCompactActivity(), MyKoinComponent {
    private val viewModel: FooViewModel by viewModel()
}
```

Ref:
https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/reference/index.html#_koin_context_isolation

Comment: Crash caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property koinApplication has not been initialized in koin 2.1.6

Comment: @aiueoH how do I start the InitKoinContentProvider? I'm not very familiarized with Content Providers

Comment: Sry for asking after many years. May I ask how you set up the unit test for MyKoinComponent? In my case, I followed the documentation but injections are still coming from MyKoinComponent.

Answer (score 5):

In your library modules, use `loadKoinModules()` to load the module-specific koin modules. [Docs](https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/start-koin?id=loading-modules-after-startkoin).

You need to have run `startKoin()` prior to that, so the init order with content providers can be a little tricky.

Comment: For example we are redirecting user to a new feature module, is it fine to call `loadKoinModules()` in the first Activitie's `onCreate()`  on that module ?

Comment: Thx for the response

Comment: What if the host app doesn't use Koin? How do we know as library developers?

Answer (score 4):

To init extra koin modules on other project modules and get no duplicate loading issues (e.g. pressing home, than coming back to the activity), go to your module declaration file:

```
val myModule = module {
    single { MyRepository(get()) }
    viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) }
}

private val loadKoinModules by lazy {
    loadKoinModules(myModule)
}

fun inject() = loadKoinModules
```

Then on your view:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    inject()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR
Use `single/factory` methods with `override` param set to `true` when providing your dependencies that are overriding those provided by the modules loaded before.

```
single<Manager>(override = true) { TestManager() }
```

I have faced a similar issue when I tried to override one of the dependencies for UI test purposes. 
When I setup in `Application.onCreate()`:

```
startKoin {
   module {
       single { Printer() }
   }
}
```

and then in `before` method of test:

```
loadKoinModules(module {
    single<Printer> { TestPrinter() }
})
```

I get a Runtime exception during the test:
`org.koin.core.error.DefinitionOverrideException: Already existing definition or try to override an existing one`

And the solution is to show Koin that you are **intentionally** overriding that dependency by using **`override`** param of `single` function like that:

```
loadKoinModules(module {
    single<Printer>(override = true) { TestPrinter() }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

By design `startKoin` is meant to be called from the Application class. You can provide a parameter in the lib whether to call `startKoin` or not. But I doubt that including such things as Koin in libs is a good practice. What if an application already includes Koin, but of different version?

Answer (score 0):

This way worked perfect for me:

```
@KoinExperimentalAPI 
class MainApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initKoin()
    }

    private fun initKoin() {
        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MainApplication)
        }
        loadKoinModules(
            myFeatureModule
        )
    }
}
```

And define you module in your feature as usual:

```
val myFeatureModule = module {
    factory<...> { ...() }

    single { ...() }

    viewModel { ...(get() }
}
```