# Koin Context Isolation: setup correctly and avoid random NoBeanDefFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I have an Android library module that I package and publish. It's a dependency in different apps, some that use Koin and some that don't, therefore I want to use Koin's [context isolation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/context-isolation).

Having followed the docs, I added a koin component and context as follows:

```kotlin
internal object LocalKoinContext {
    lateinit var koinApplication: KoinApplication
}

// Custom KoinComponent using the local instance & not the Global context
interface CustomKoinComponent : KoinComponent {
    // override the used Koin instance to use the local koin application instance (LocalKoinContext.koinApplication)
    override fun getKoin(): Koin = LocalKoinContext.koinApplication.koin
}
```

and add create the koinApplication  like this:

```kotlin
// Local Koin application instance
LocalKoinContext.koinApplication = koinApplication {
    // use AndroidLogger as Koin Logger - default Level.INFO
    androidLogger(Level.ERROR)

    // use the Android context given there
    androidContext(applicationContext)

    // load properties from assets/koin.properties file
    androidFileProperties()

    // declare used modules
    modules(theModule)
}
```

I have an activity that uses a view model that lives within the local Koin component and I used to instantiate the koinApplication within the `onCreate` of the that activity:

```kotlin
class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
    CustomKoinComponent {

    private val sharedViewModel by viewModel<MySharedViewModel>()
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        // Local Koin application instance
        LocalKoinContext.koinApplication = koinApplication {
             // use AndroidLogger as Koin Logger - default Level.INFO
             androidLogger(Level.ERROR)

             // use the Android context given there
             androidContext(applicationContext)

             // load properties from assets/koin.properties file
             androidFileProperties()

             // declare used modules
             modules(theModule)
         }
     }
```

The issue is that I get random `NoBeanDefFoundException`

```
Caused by org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'my.package.name.MySharedViewModel'. Check your definitions!
       at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.java:264)
       at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.java:233)
       at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.java:204)
       at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.factory.DefaultViewModelFactory.create(DefaultViewModelFactory.java:11)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
       at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolverKt.get(ViewModelResolverKt.java:23)
       at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolverKt.resolveInstance(ViewModelResolverKt.java:12)
       at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExtKt.java:86)
       at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExtKt.java:72)
       at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.ViewModelStoreOwnerExtKt.getViewModel(ViewModelStoreOwnerExtKt.java:68)
       at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.ViewModelStoreOwnerExtKt.getViewModel$default(ViewModelStoreOwnerExtKt.java:58)
       at my.package.name.FirstActivity$special$$inlined$viewModel$default$1.invoke(FirstActivity.java:75)
```

I suspect it's because sometimes the koinApplication doesn't have time to set itself up but as it's rare I haven't been able to reproduce the issue.

In the answer to [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56352142/2414033), the dev creates a `ContentProvider` to instantiate the koinApplication. I've tried it out and so far so good (although, I will only know in months from now), but is this truly the way to go? Seems to be an overkill to have to create a content provider just for that.

Can anyone shed some light on where we are supposed to instantiate the local `KoinApplication`?

Comment: I can't say I've done this myself, but the stack trace would imply the viewmodel isn't set up in your modules, so you might wanna include those in the question. Also, given the naming of your class, you probably want to use the `by sharedViewModel` delegate instead of `by viewModel`

Comment: Also - depending on your actual goal with this, you might find using Scopes a path of less resistance - would still allow you to use the traditional global `startKoin` and offer the encapsulation I presume you're looking for https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/scope/

Comment: @lase the viewmodel is in the modules otherwise it would not work at all. Concerning the use of `by sharedViewModel`or `by viewModel` [the docs are pretty clear about it](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel/#shared-viewmodel). The fact that it's a library, packaged as a dependency, and used in different apps makes the use of Scopes trickier. Maybe I go it wrong, but I wasn't able to get apps, both using and not using Koin, to handle them well. I'd love to see an example of how that would work.

Comment: Maybe you got hit by this bug: https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1314

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone shed some light on where we are supposed to instantiate the local KoinApplication?

You should do this inside your Application level class, for example this is what I have on my Application class onCreate

```kotlin
startKoin {
            androidLogger(Level.ERROR)
            androidContext(this@VeroApp)
            modules(AppModules.modules) <-- list of defined koin modules
        }
```

I'm not so sure about the usage of local KoinApplication interface. I know that AppCompatActivity for example is out of the box supported and you can just do a without extending anything

```kotlin
private val sharedViewModel by viewModel<MySharedViewModel>()
```

Comment: I edited the question as it seems that it's not clear that my lib is distributed and used in different kinds of apps. Some use Koin and some don't. The reason I use context isolation is to avoid conflicts.